# UI routing not working, angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I'm trying to display main.html template via UI routing, but its not working for some reason. Can someone please point out the mistake in my code. Thank you.

**appModule**

```
"use strict";

angular.module("fleetOperate", ["ui.router", "mainModule"]);
```

---

**UI Routing**

```
"use strict";

angular.module('fleetOperate').config(function ($stateProvider) {

    $stateProvider
    .state('main', {
        url: '/main',
        templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html'

    })

});
```

---

**mainModule**

```
"use strict";

angular.module("mainModule", []);
```

---

**main.HTML**

```
<div class="icon-bar" ui-view="main">
    <a ui-sref="" class="item">
        <i class="fa fa-truck" style="font-size:48px;"></i>
        <label>Fleet</label>
    </a>

    <a ui-sref="" class="item">
        <i class="fa fa-users" style="font-size:48px;"></i>
        <label>Drivers</label>
    </a>

    <a href="#" class="item">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar" style="font-size:48px;"></i>
        <label>Planner</label>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="item">
        <i class="fa fa-truck" style="font-size:48px;"></i>
        <label>Trailors</label>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="item">
        <i class="fa fa-files-o" style="font-size:48px;"></i>
        <label>Pod</label>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="item">
        <i class="fa fa-cog" style="font-size:48px;"></i>
        <label>Settings</label>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="item">
        <i class="fa fa-square-o" style="font-size:48px;"></i>
        <label>Control Center</label>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="item">
        <i class="fa fa-phone" style="font-size:48px;"></i>
        <label>Communication</label>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="item">
        <i class="fa fa-user" style="font-size:48px;"></i>
        <label>Customer Profile</label>
    </a>

</div>
```

---

**Index.HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="fleetOperate">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title>Truck Trackers</title>


    <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link href="app/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link href="app/main/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />


    <script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

    <script src="app/main/mainModule.js"></script>

    <script src="app/appModule.js"></script>
    <script src="app/appUI_Routing.js"></script>


</head>
<body class="container-fluid">
    <header class="js-title-bar">

        <div class="js-logo-area">
            <img class="js-icon" ng-src="http://www.cam-trucks.com/images/2.jpg"/>
            <div class="js-title-area">
                <p class="js-logo-title"> <strong>Truck Tracker's</strong></p>
                <p class="js-logo-subtitle">Where ever you GO, we FIND you !</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </header>

    <div ui-view></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: does it give any error message in console, or just doing nothing?

Comment: No errors in the console. Just loads the header and routing is not working.

Comment: Did you setup a default view? `angular.module('fleetOperate').config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/main");[...]});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Update your UI Router:

```
angular.module('fleetOperate').config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("main");
$stateProvider
.state('main', {
    url: '/main',
    templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html'

})
});
```

Comment: Hi Maher, can you please check this question and help me what the mistake is in the code? Thank you.

http://stackoverflow.com/q/34668416/5724169